# stripe - find out which payment method did customer use

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using two different payment methods in my Stripe checkout, 'card' and 'sofort'.
For statistics purposes, I want to find out which payment method did my customer use after payment succeeded.

I had a look at the session I get back after checkout. But I couldn't find any useful information.

Did anyone solved this issue? Thanks

EDIT (Solution in Java):

```
    RequestOptions requestOptions = RequestOptions.builder().setStripeAccount(retrieveKey("CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID")).build();
    
    PaymentIntent paymentIntent = PaymentIntent.retrieve(paymentIntentID, requestOptions);
                
    List<Charge> charges = paymentIntent.getCharges().getData();
    
    for (Charge cg : charges) {
        paymentMethodType = cg.getPaymentMethodDetails().getType(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using Checkout, the returned `session` object will include the associated `payment_intent` ID, which can be used with [Retrieve a `PaymentIntent`](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_intents/retrieve).

When retrieving the `PaymentIntent` you can optionally 'expand' the `payment_method` field, which will return the full [`pm_` object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/object) associated with the payment. This will include all details, including `type` field.

This will differ depending on your language/integration. Using Node.js:

```js
stripe.paymentIntents.retrieve('pi_XXX', {
  expand: ['payment_method'],
});
```

Comment: You mean 'payment_method_details' field. Yes it works. Thank you very much.

Comment: @codyLine Alternatively you can expand the PaymentIntent and paymentMethod when retrieving the checkout session.

There's a video example of this [here](https://youtu.be/3-erqAmS8Ak?t=293).

Comment: Nice video. I posted my solution (see 'Edit' in my question).